# How can we distinguish fold and cycle of sedimentation on a remote sensing image or in the field?

Tags: geology, remote-sensing, tectonics, structural-geology, stratigraphy

A fold is composed of stratigraphy that is symmetric and repeated. Cyclic sediments (also called rhythmic sediments) are sequences of sedimentary rocks that are characterised by repetitive patterns of different rock types (strata) or facies within the sequence (wiki). A cycle of sendimentation is usually composed of transgressive and regressive deposition, so the sequences can be also likely symmetric.

One method to distinguish them, I think, is the stratigraphic occurrence. Is there other methods that can help distinguish them on a remote sensing image? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe whether structural traces are developed can be also used to distinguish them?